# Confusion in longitude range, why do they start at 80?

Tags: latitude-longitude, gis-principle

In one of our notes in the university, there's a paragraph about latitude and longitude that tell us this:

> Geographic coordinates are the earth's latitude and longitude system,
> ranging from 90 degrees south to 90 degrees north in latitude and **80
> degrees west to 180 degrees east in longitude**

I understand the part for the latitude, since every diagram labels -90S to 90N. But, why do they define for latitude as: *80 degrees west to 180 degrees east in longitude*. As far as I understand latitudes also start from 0 to (-/+)180. So, why does it seem like they're somehow omitting a 10 degress of range?

Comment: You understand everything correctly, it's just that someone made a mistake and typed 80 instead of 180...so he missed not 10 but 100 degrees...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a typo and should correctly read like this:

"Geographic coordinates are the earth's latitude and longitude system, ranging from 90 degrees south to 90 degrees north in latitude and ***180*** degrees west to 180 degrees east in longitude"

Please note,

> The 180th meridian is one of the shames of geospatial technology. The story goes that given the rules of
>
> - LineStrings and Polygons are represented as collections of positions
> - Positions should be within -180° and 180° longitude and -90° and 90° latitude
>   It is simply impossible to tell the difference between a line that goes from -179° around the world to 179°, or one that just hops over the 180th meridian. That’s one problem with Cartesian coordinates on a sphere.

For further information see [The 180th Meridian](https://macwright.com/2016/09/26/the-180th-meridian.html).